# Realtime motion detection using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, real-time, detection, motion

I have a project where I need to detect motion in a video stream. When motion is detected further processing is done. There is no need for detection of an area where the motion was detected or more detailed information. I only need to measure the percentage of changed pixels between two images or something similar as a trigger for further processing.

My idea was to take the absolute difference of the two images, threshold it and count pixels. I'm using cv::absdiff, cv::threshold and cv::countNonZero. This calculation takes about 10 ms for a full HD image. At 30 fps this adds up to 10 * 30 = 300 ms on a single core.

This doesn't yet include grayscale conversion for the image which takes roughly 2-3 times compared to the difference image calculation. So I can process about 10 fps in full HD on a single core.

I'm now looking for a way to speed up grayscale conversion/motion detection in a significant way. What would be the fastest way of motion detection in an RGB video stream in terms of computation power?

Answer (score 1):

If you are completely constrained to a single core, this doesn't apply. However, if you have a good video card, you can use gpu:: or ocl:: functions. By using these you can speed up the operation 3-30x! I know for a fact that gpu::threshold is much faster than cpu version. I can thresh a 1080p picture in 0.001 seconds on an geForce gtx660. 
Further examples of my GPU times on the same size image: 
masking - .002, 
LBP classifying - .053, 
morphological .002.

Comment: I'm not constrained to a single core. Calculation relative to a single CPU serves as an indication for myself how many instances I can run in parallel. gpu:: only supports nvidia devices. I'm stuck with some intel gpu so only ocl:: is available to me. How much time will it take to copy my image data to gpu memory?

Answer (score 1):

1. Resize the image down before processing
2. Apply a blur before testing as this decreases noise.

opencv has methods for comparing mats together, e.g. cv::compare which has overloaded the relative operators.

Also, there's a huge difference in terms of speed between the debug opencv libraries and the release libraries, to the point, before you fret about speeds, do a release compile using the release libraries of opencv.